# 分割して抽出したデータの取り扱いについて

Tags: sql

SQLでレコード数の多いデータを複数のクエリで分割して抽出した後の結合について質問です。

データ抽出後にエクセルやR,Pythonなどで分析や加工をする場合はデータの結合が必要になるかと思いますが、
分割したデータを結合したファイルはとても重くなることが想像できます。

一般的にどのような方法で分割したデータの結合を行うのが良いのか教えていただけますと幸いです。

※イメージ※
重いデータを10個のクエリで分割して抽出
→分割したデータを一つにまとめて統計解析やグラフ作成を行いたい

Comment: **抽出した後** の話であるなら元が SQL かはあまり関係なくて、抽出後に扱いたい言語に対象を絞った聞き方をしたほうが、よい回答が集まりやすくなる気がします。

Comment: １回のクエリで抽出されるデータ(レコード)の量は、どのぐらいなのですか？ データ量の桁は、Mega(１００万)、Giga(10億)、Tera(1兆)?　また、抽出された１レコードに含まれるフィールド数は、どのぐらいなのでしょうか。

Comment: ギガぐらいのデータ量です。

Comment: フィールド数は10程度です。

Comment: 抽出したデータの形式も気になるところです。JSONなど特殊な形式ですと変換作業が必要ですが単純なCSV等であれば、ファイル同士を結合するだけなのでコマンド一発でできると思います。ギガレベルのテキストデータをコピペやソフトを使ってマージするのはさすがに難しいでしょう。